# What does "{main}" in the getTraceAsString() return value mean?

Tags: php, debugging, exception, stack-trace

I'm consistently getting an additional stack frame when I look at an exception's trace with the `getTraceAsString()` method. It's neither visible in `getTrace()` nor in `debug_backtrace()`. Where does it come from and what does it mean?

For example, this script:

```
function foo () {
    echo "== debug_backtrace() ==\n";
    foreach (debug_backtrace() as $i => $frame) {
        echo "#$i $frame[file]($frame[line]): $frame[function]()\n";
    }
    throw new Exception();
}

function bar () {
    foo();
}

try {
    bar();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "\n== getTrace() ==\n";
    foreach ($e->getTrace() as $i => $frame) {
        echo "#$i $frame[file]($frame[line]): $frame[function]()\n";
    }
    echo "\n== getTraceAsString() ==\n";
    echo $e->getTraceAsString(), "\n";
}
```

produces the following output:

```
== debug_backtrace() ==
#0 /home/foo/tests/php/test4.php(13): foo()
#1 /home/foo/tests/php/test4.php(17): bar()

== getTrace() ==
#0 /home/foo/tests/php/test4.php(13): foo()
#1 /home/foo/tests/php/test4.php(17): bar()

== getTraceAsString() ==
#0 /home/foo/tests/php/test4.php(13): foo()
#1 /home/foo/tests/php/test4.php(17): bar()
#2 {main}
```

The only other place where I've seen {main} was with Xdebug. I guess it's some internal PHP stack frame, but why is it only visible when getting the trace as a string?

Comment: Seems to be less interesting, since it appears in a consistent way. Most likely just an annoyance.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.main.php